# Adding multiple rows in database table from fetched result through a loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php4

i have table named subscribers in my database and i am fetching it through while loop in a form and i have given some options like how much copies are to be sent, how the copies will be sent.
I want to insert the data of the form in table name record once the submit button is pressed but what my code does is it just inserts the last row to the table.
here is my code

```
<table class="table table-hover" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Send</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Copies</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form method="post">                                    
      <?php
        $i=1;
        $query="SELECT * FROM subscribers ";
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Q Err");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

          $id=$row['id'];
          $name=$row['name'];
          $stdate=$row['starting_date'];
          $mndate=$row['ending_date'];
          $sub=$row['subcription_no'];

      ?>          
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?>

        </td>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></td>
        <td><select name="send">
          <option>Yes</option>
          <option>No</option>
          </select>
        </td>          
        <td><select name="method">
          <option>Postal</option>
          <option>By Hand</option>
          <option>Courier</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="copy"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <?php
  $i++;
} ?>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;
        </td>          
        <td>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Print"/>
        </td>
      </tr>                
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){

  $name1=$_POST['name'];
  $send1=$_POST['send'];
  $method1=$_POST['method'];
  $copy1=$_POST['copy'];


  $query2="Insert into shortlist values('','$id','$name1','$send1','$method1','$copy1',NOW())";
  $sql2=mysqli_query($con,$query2)or die("Q ERR 2");    

}?>
```

Comment: please format it proper so we can understand

Comment: ok just give me a sec